# How to use a global .env file at root with SvelteKit and Turborepo?

Tags: environment-variables, sveltekit, monorepo, pnpm, turborepo

Is there a way to share a `.env.local` env variables file through my entire Turborepo app? So far it is not recognized through my SvelteKit website

I've seen around that I could use `dotenv-cli` in the `package.json` scripts but I'd like to avoid it, as I'd have to add it to every single app/package that would need access to the env variables.

```json
"with-env": "dotenv -e ./.env --",
"dev": "pnpm with-env vite dev",
```

I also have this in my `turbo.json` but that doesn't seem to help

```json
"globalDependencies": [".env.local"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It appears you can do something like this in your `svelte.config.js` file:

```js
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
        env: {
            dir: '../..'
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

This will allow SvelteKit to find your .env file in the root of your Turborepo. The documentation for this can be found here: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#env

You can leave the `"globalDependencies": [".env.local"]` in your turbo.json in order to invalidate the cache whenever the env variables change.

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working with a .env.local file at the root of the project 

Comment: @flks were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I haven't tried recently, maybe things might have changed